# Adding extra information to the Twilio POST response

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

Is there an attribute I can add to the `client.calls.create({` method which would allow me to add extra information to the request body that Twilio will post in the callback URL? Something like this:

```
client.calls.create({
                method: 'GET',
                extraInfo: { employeeID: 'ABC123' }, <-- This would be what I want to add to the JSON response.
                statusCallback: `${config.host}/completed`,
                statusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
                twiml: responseString,
                to: data.number`,
                from: `+1${availableNumbers[0]}`
            })
```

Would have Twilio return this to my callback URL:

```
{
  "extraInfo": { employeeID: 'ABC123' }, <-- This would be what should be added to the POST request
  "account_sid": "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "annotation": null,
  "answered_by": null,
  "api_version": "2010-04-01",
  "caller_name": null,
  "date_created": "Tue, 31 Aug 2010 20:36:28 +0000",
  "date_updated": "Tue, 31 Aug 2010 20:36:44 +0000",
  "direction": "inbound",
  "duration": "15",
  "end_time": "Tue, 31 Aug 2010 20:36:44 +0000",
  "forwarded_from": "+141586753093",
  "from": "+18668675310",
  "from_formatted": "(866) 867-5310",
  "group_sid": null,
  "parent_call_sid": null,
  "phone_number_sid": "PNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "price": "-0.03000",
  "price_unit": "USD",
  "sid": "CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "start_time": "Tue, 31 Aug 2010 20:36:29 +0000",
  "status": "completed",
  "subresource_uris": {
    "notifications": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls/CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Notifications.json",
    "recordings": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls/CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Recordings.json",
    "feedback": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls/CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Feedback.json",
    "feedback_summaries": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls/FeedbackSummary.json",
    "payments": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls/CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Payments.json"
  },
  "to": "+14155551212",
  "to_formatted": "(415) 555-1212",
  "trunk_sid": null,
  "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Calls/CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.json",
  "queue_time": "1000"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the twiml parameter, use the url parameter and append HTTP query parameters to the end of the URL. You can do the same with the statusCallback URL.

[Passing Custom Information via Requests to Twilio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011213347-Passing-Custom-Information-via-Requests-to-Twilio)

[How to Share Information Between Your Applications](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/how-share-information-between-your-applications)